# Bubble Chart Creation

Tags: r

If I have the data set

```
       Class        Percent Attended            Percent Participated
         3                 .8                             .6
         3                 .5                              .4
         2                 .9                             .5
         7                 .92                            .8
```

So on and so forth, I am trying to create a bubble chart in which it shows the average of each class Percent Attended vs Percent Participated and labeled by Class

I have tried the aggregate function and the ggplot function with + point with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


df1 <- df %>% group_by(Class) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Percent_Attended, y = Percent_Participated)) + 
        geom_point(aes(color = factor(Class)), size = 3)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
structure(list(Class = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 7L), Percent_Attended = c(0.8, 
0.5, 0.9, 0.92), Percent_Participated = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8)), .Names = c("Class", 
"Percent_Attended", "Percent_Participated"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Was looking for more of a scatterplot type deal where Percent Participated was Y-axis and Percent Attended is X-Axis and these points would be labeled by the class they are from